# How to format pd.to_excel() headers?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas library exports dataframe into Excel with its own format which is bold, centered, bordered headers. However, I want to customize my headers with my own style while exporting. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the development version of pandas which contains styling ability to format headers. This does not exist prior to version 1.4.0

Comment: Where can I read more about that? I can't find any info on https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#styler

Comment: Its the first bullet point from the link you just posted. And you can see more examples in the Styler user guide for 1.4.0